# Php Game Sql Problems

Tags: php, sql, game-engine

I need help with this code, i need it to add an array in Gangs
under members and seperate them with -

I need every member in the Gang to be listed under Members and separated with -
so i can explode them below.

This is the line that adds the members to gangs but its without - and i think it erases members that are already there.

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE Gangs SET members='".$name."'WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gang_name'])."'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

full code

```
if(isset($_POST['creategang'])){

if(empty($_POST['gang_name'])){ 
echo "Enter a Gang Name.";
} else {

if (strlen($_POST['gang_name']) > "20"){
echo "The username may not consist out of more then 20 characters.";
}else{

if (ereg('[^A-Za-z0-9]', $_POST['gang_name'])) {
echo "Invalid Name only A-Z,a-z and 0-9 is allowed.";
}else{
$sql = "SELECT name FROM Gangs WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gang_name'])."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$m_count = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($m_count >= "1"){
echo 'This name has already been used.!';
}else{
$sql = "INSERT INTO Gangs SET name = '".$_POST['gang_name']."' , owner= '$name'";

$res = mysql_query($sql);

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET gang='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gang_name'])."' WHERE id='" .mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']). "'") 
or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE Gangs SET members='".$name."'WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gang_name'])."'")
or die(mysql_error());

echo 'Gang successfully created!';
}
}
}
}
}
?>
```

this is the code i will use to separate the array

```
$Gang_array = explode("-", $Gang_members);
```

Thanks for viewing my question and thanks in advance for helping me

new code to add to gang

```
<? include_once("connect.php"); ?>

<?
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
 // Login OK, update last active

 $sql = "UPDATE users SET lastactive=NOW() WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."'";
 mysql_query($sql);

}else{
   header("Location: index.php");
     exit();
 }
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
$id = htmlspecialchars($row->id);
$userip = htmlspecialchars($row->userip);
$name = htmlspecialchars($row->name);
$sitestate = htmlspecialchars($row->sitestate);
$password = htmlspecialchars($row->password);
$mail = htmlspecialchars($row->mail);
$money = htmlspecialchars($row->money);
$exp = htmlspecialchars($row->exp);
$rank = htmlspecialchars($row->rank);
$health = htmlspecialchars($row->health);
$points = htmlspecialchars($row->points);
$profile = htmlspecialchars($row->profile);
$gang = htmlspecialchars($row->gang);
?>

<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Gangs WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
$Gang_name = htmlspecialchars($row->name);
$Gang_owner = htmlspecialchars($row->owner);
$Gang_money = htmlspecialchars($row->money);
$Gang_exp = htmlspecialchars($row->exp);
$Gang_level = htmlspecialchars($row->level);
$Gang_members = htmlspecialchars($row->members);
$Gang_array = explode("-", $Gang_members);



$Gang_profile = htmlspecialchars($row->profile);

?>
<div id="content" class="profile">
    <h2>Gang Profile</h2>
<form method="post" >
<input type="submit" name="Petition" id="Petition" value="Petition">
</form>
<center>
<h1><?php echo $Gang_name; ?></h1>
Owner: <?php echo $Gang_owner; ?><br>
Gang Cash: $<?php echo $Gang_money; ?><br>
Gang Exp: <?php echo $Gang_exp; ?><br>
Gang Level: <?php echo $Gang_level; ?><br>
Gang Members: <?php echo $Gang_array; ?><br>
</center><br>
<p>Gang Quote</p>
<div id="UserText">
      <?php
    $Gang_profile = htmlentities($Gang_profile);
    $Gang_profile = nl2br($Gang_profile); 
    $Gang_profile = stripslashes($Gang_profile);
    echo $Gang_profile; ?>
</div>
</div>

<? 
if (isset($_POST['Petition'])) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT members FROM Gangs 
      WHERE name='".$Gang_name."'");
if ($result) {
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $members = $row['members'];
      }
}
if ($members != '') $members .= '-'.$name;
else $members = $name;
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE Gangs SET members='".$members."' WHERE name='".$Gang_name."'");

}
```

Comment: Can you provide your table structure and its relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly. You can try this :

Get the members first :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT members FROM Gangs 
      WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gang_name'])."'");
if ($result) {
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $members = $row['members'];
      }
}
```

Then add new member and do update :

```
//This is to check whether $name is already in the gangs
if (strpos($members,$name) !== false) {
    if ($members != '') $members .= '-'.$name;
    else $members = $name;

    //Update to gangs
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE Gangs SET members='".$members."' WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gang_name'])."'");
}
else sprintf("%s is in the gangs already",$name);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thought it was working but i added test to Gangs it comes up as -test then i add test 2 now i only have -test2 in the gang insteant of -test-test2

Comment: can you show me the query to select the members and also the result?

Comment: opps im sorry i forgot to change a line in the code i had to use this in another spot for others to be added into the gang ill update the post with this code forgot to change the post where it searches the members

Comment: @Tprice88 I've updated my answer, I thought I was wrong with the index name. It should be `$row['members']` not `$row['member']`. Also I added a condition to check whether members is '', we don't need to add '-' on it.

Comment: awesome that works perfect, do u know a check if your in the members allready

Comment: @Tprice88 please check my answer again. I've modified it to check whether the name is in the gangs already. It should work. IMHO your database structure is not good enough. If I may suggest you, you'd better to create a separate table for members, then define the relationship between gangs and members (whether it is 1-n, n-1 or n-m).

Comment: not sure how i would do that i have 1 table for users and 1 table for gangs, might be better to search the users table if there in the gang or not  cuz i added it on users also for it to appear on users profile. but im not sure if it will work that way. i need a gang profile also that will list every member of the gang.

Comment: ill add my whole code and let me know if u see a way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code, but this should probably work:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE Gangs SET members = members + '-' + '".$name."'WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gang_name'])."'")
or die(mysql_error());
```